# How to push temporary changes?

Tags: git

Git noob here. Here's my conundrum:

1. I want to push code to have a log of my effort & history of changes
2. The new code is not finished yet, and will break

Is there a way to "lightly" push changes, just to show what I've been working on, but won't update others' local files if they pull the Branch?

I usually push code like this:

```
git add .
git commit -m "this code doesn't work yet, and shouldn't be pulled"
git pull origin myBranch
git status
git pull origin myBranch
```

What should I use to accomplish this? A new Branch? A Fork? I'm not too sure about the terminology, if I knew I could easily goog it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Just push to a different branch. This is an issue of branch policies, which your team needs to define.

Comment: OK, so I should have a "WillBreak" or "Dev" Branch for cases like this, but it's something my team should agree on, or is it no big deal to just create my own Dev branch? And, when the code is stable, I push to the original branch instead?

Comment: Yes x1000 to this. If you're pushing up your own feature branch and your team is pulling it into master without you having made a pull request with your branch, then you've got a team issue, not a git issue. You should be able to push up your own branches as much as you want without fear of breaking something. That's what branches are for.

Comment: When your dev/feature/whatever branch is ready, you _merge_ it to your master/stable/integration whatever branch. This way no-one sees the changes until they're ready, unless they choose to look at your work-in-progress branch, but you still have a record of all the changes.

Comment: @TravisHeeter name your branch whatever you want. You don't need to append "WillBreak" or "WIP" on it. It's a branch – it's understood that it's a work in progress. And if your teammates don't want to use a branch with broken components, they don't have to pull it down.

Answer (score 2):

If you push your changes on the remote repo, your teammates will see theses changes, so a good practice is to create a `feature` branch (see the [git-flow recommendation](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)) which will be merged into the current branch latter.

In this feature branch you can push useless commits, it doesn't matter if you push bad commits messages **BUT** once you are ready to merge the feature branch into the branch used by your mates you can run this command before **git rebase -i**, in order to rewrite the history to keep only useful commits messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can commit your work to as many local (meaning stored in the `.git` directory next to your working copy) branches as you wish, without ever pushing them to another repository (on a central server for instance).

This way you have a record of your work without affecting others.

Once you know that your work is ready for others to use, you can push.

Comment: OK, what would that look like in Git Bash?

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as a "light" branch in `git`. There is no way to make a remote branch that would be available for pulling for others but would not modify a local working tree.

You need to push a branch somehow marked as yet unfinished. A popular
method is to append `[WIP]` to branch names or commits messages to
indicate that they are `Work in Progresss`:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/merge_requests/work_in_progress_merge_requests.html

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html#wip

Or from https://github.com/blog/1943-how-to-write-the-perfect-pull-request:

> Be explicit about when you want feedback, if the Pull Request is work
>   in progress, say so. A prefix of “[WIP]” in the title is a simple,
>   common pattern to indicate that state.

Comment: OK, so instead of `git push origin myBranch` I should do `git push origin myBranch[WIP]`?

Comment: Naming a branch `myBranch[WIP]` seems good to me but you need to tell your team members what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: A branch is inherently "Work in Progress". You don't ever need to include "WIP" in the branch name.

Comment: I don't agree with that. There may be multiple branches in the repository and only some of them may be suitable for merging into stable branch, some may be pushed for backup or as a proof of concept. And I wouldn't call `master` branch a `Work in Progress` branch - it's supposed to be stable.

Comment: `master` isn't a feature branch. And if you have branches that shouldn't be merged, don't create a pull request for them. Obviously, use whatever works for you and your team – I've just personally never encountered a situation in working with many different teams over the years where that would be helpful/meaningful.

Comment: But who's talking about `pull requests`? `OP` just wants to push a branch. In some systems such as `Gitlab` you cannot merge in the `pull request` that has `WIP` somewhere in its name - it's a `Gitlab` built-in feature. In `Gerrit` there are `drafts`. I agree that all branches should be finally merged into a stable branch or abandoned but can stop people from pushing yet unfinished code to gather opinions from others before at an early stage where mistakes could be more easily avoided.

Comment: RE: "But who's talking about `pull requests`?" – According to your own comment (mentioned once) and your own answer (mentioned 4 times), you are? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I just mentioned that to show that `WIP` commonly is commonly used. I suggested pushing a branch. However, making a pull request and marking it as `WIP` also makes sense to me.